# Is it possible to measure how long it takes a Winforms form to appear?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I have a winforms app, and pops up some windows from time to time depending on what the user clicks on. Lately, users have been complaining that the pop ups take too long to appear. If I profile the code, or put in a Stopwatch, I see that my C# code finishes process the Show() method in about 50ms, but the window itself won't appear for almost a second.

Is there any way to measure that amount time until the window actually appears?

Answer (score 3):

I think the Shown event fires after the drawing is completed.

See [`Form.Shown` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) and [Order of Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)

Comment: Actually this will not measure how long it takes for your form to appear. Or at least, when I checked this out, the Shown event fired after 50ms, but the form wasn't visible for a couple hundred milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Measuring the time until the first `OnPaint` call could be a way. It is called as a response to the `WM_PAINT` message, which is sent by Windows to a Window when it should be redrawn. If you take a measurement both before and after the `base.OnPaint()` call you can also see how long the actual drawing code takes to complete.